# how to get event when column changed it position?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-grid

I am using **UI-grid**  .In that I am using column moving functionality from here .
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/217_column_moving
Using that user change grid column position .I want a event when it successfully change the position of column.
I want to show a alert after changing the position of column ..In other word I want to add callback function when it column is successfully drop .

Here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/osrmsawxqhA7pEHYP1EE?p=preview
I want to show alert after column position is changed

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div class="grid" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-move-columns></div>
</div>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the API:

`gridApi.colMovable.on.columnPositionChanged(scope,function(colDef, originalPosition, newPosition){})`

Add following code snippet:

```
  $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
gridApi.colMovable.on.columnPositionChanged($scope,function(colDef, originalPosition, newPosition){
  alert('test');
})
```

};

http://plnkr.co/edit/DRl6sn4Wyk8uaurvVrwt?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

**Used following code to handle column changed event**

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        $scope.gridApi.colMovable.on.columnPositionChanged();

      };
```

**Used "ui-grid-move-columns" directive to handle column move events**

```
<div class="grid" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-move-columns></div>
```